# R replace duplicate values in a factor level

Tags: r, replace

This is my attempt to create reproducible data for my question:

```
df<-as.data.frame(cbind("value"=rnorm(29),"both.dates"=c(
"July July","July August","July October","July November","July December",
"August August","August October","August November","August December",
"September August","September September", "September October",
"September November","September December","October August",
"October September", "October October","October November",
"October December","November August","November September", 
"November October", "November November","November December",
"December August", "December September", "December October", 
"December November","December December")))
df$value<-as.numeric(df$value)
head(df)
> head(df)
value    both.dates
1     2     July July
2     8   July August
3    22  July October
4     3 July November
5    12 July December
6    17 August August
```

I have data that look like the column "`both.dates`". "August December" are the same thing as "December August" and I would like to replace all occurrences of "December August" with "August December".

I have tried `replace()` but that doesn't work for factors.
Thank you.

Comment: To make it truly reproducible you should put set.seed at the beginning (e.g. `set.seed(123)`)

Comment: I think you need to split the column and then sort `m1 <- do.call(rbind,strsplit(as.character(df$both.dates),  ' '));
t(apply(m1,1, sort))` If there are multiple items to replace

Comment: After replacing some of the factors, you can drop the unused levels on the data.frame by doing `df <- droplevels(df)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose, you want to replace `every` duplicates, you can `split` the string and then `sort` it after specifying the levels as `month.name`.  This would ensure that the order would be the same as in the month order.

```
df$both.dates <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$both.dates), ' '),
       function(x) paste(sort(factor(x, levels= month.name)),
                 collapse=' '))
```

Comment: This worked, but I had to define df$both.dates as a factor afterwards

Comment: @K.Brannen Glad to know it worked.  You can wrap `factor(sapply(...)`